# Viewmodel has lots of properties which bind to view

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a configuration View. so it binds a lot of properties in `Viewmodel`. But I have a another class `People` and I want to assign properties of viewmodel to class `People`.

```
class Viewmodel 
{
   public string name {get;set;}
   public int age {get;set;}
   public string nationality {get;set;}
   public string hobby {get;set;}
   ………… 

}

class People
{
   public string name {get;set;}
   public int age {get;set;}
   public string nationality {get;set;}
   public string hobby {get;set;}
   public People[] friends {get;set;}
   ………… 
   public void AddFriend(People people)
   {
    //add friend to this
   }
}
```

I have to write a function:

```
void Assign()
{ 
  People.name = Viewmodel.name;
  People.age= Viewmodel.age;
  …………
}
```

How could I refactor this function? I usually will define more than 10 properties in viewmodel.

Comment: Wich class contains this method?

Comment: Assign() is in Viewmodel.In order to assign information in Viewmodel to People.Then class People will be serialize into XML.You know, I'm confused about if these properties shoudle be assigned one by one. It will increase lines of code.

Comment: @Heslacher sorry forgot to @ you

Comment: No problem. Does the `ViewModel` only assign its values to `People`?

Comment: Looks to me like your `ViewModel` should simply have one property of type `People`. However for future reference, you can use a tool like Automapper to make assignments like this.

Comment: @Heslacher i'm not sure, you know, consumer demand is changeability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very common problem while working with MVVM. I believe the best solution to resolve this is to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in Models; that way you can directly bind the model properties in view and there will be no need to update them explicitly.

Even MS prescribes doing that -

> Typically, the model implements the facilities that make it easy to
>   bind to the view. This usually means it supports property and
>   collection changed notification through the INotifyPropertyChanged and
>   INotifyCollectionChanged interfaces. Models classes that represent
>   collections of objects typically derive from the
>   ObservableCollection class, which provides an implementation of the
>   INotifyCollectionChanged interface.

Taken from - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(PandP.40).aspx

Although its up to you to decide whether you want that type of implementation or not; and sometimes its not possible to do this too (e.g. you don't have ownership of model classes).

In case you have doubts about implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` in Models, have a look at following SO question -

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922130/in-mvvm-model-should-the-model-implement-inotifypropertychanged-interface

Comment: I've implemented INotifyPropertyChanged.This is a example code.Even though I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged,i still assigned much properties to class people. I think INotifyPropertyChanged is a binding between View and ViewModel,it can't eliminate lots of properties be assigned.

Comment: @Spark Sorry but I am not sure what you mean; My suggestion was to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on model class i.e. People in your case, I think you are talking about implementing it on Viewmodel. If you implement it on People class and have a single property in Viewmodel(say People) then you can use it directly in xaml for binding like this - {Binding People.name); without duplicating them in viewmodel.

Comment: Also, INotifyPropertyChanged is not at all related to WPF or MVVM; its a totally different concept which can be used by any class to provide change notifications to its clients. Pls. refer to answers in SO question I have added in answer.

Answer (score 2):

In case that this is actual code, I've got a couple of small remarks:

1. Microsoft's standard is that [properties are PascalCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx).
2. "People" is plural, and therefor a bad name for a class IMHO. Someone isn't a "people", he's a person.
3. `Viewmodel` is a bad name for a class. It should be `ViewModel` anyway since it is a compound word and [the first letter of each subsequent concatenated word needs to be capitalized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: It's a example code.But I would like to thank for you information.